Reliability of Web Push Notifications in PWA
As of November 2024, what is the reliability of Web Push Notifications in Android and iOS mobile devices? I have read on several pages such as this post and the Chromium support link in that post bug.
Seems to me that Web Push notifications are simply not production-ready for PWA's on Android (seems like it is working on iOS as of 2024?). The main issue seems to be waking up the device when in doze or sleep mode.
Is there somebody who has been able to successfully launch web push in production and managed to solve this somehow or is it simply not technically possible right now?
We would like to use PWA and if there is some setting we can guide our users to in order to enable them to always receive notifications, that is acceptable, but its not acceptable that the notifications are simply not arriving when one has subscribed to them and the reason is that the phone is just inactive for an hour or so.
In the bug post above they talk a lot about Chrome specifically, would it make any difference if we instruct our users to install the PWA with another browser for instance.
Insights and experiences highly appreciated. Any solution to this is highly appreciated even if it is instructing the user to do something in order to make this work. We instruct our users to actually install the app (Install App option in Chrome and Add to Home Screen in iOS).
If this is simply not possible, is there any other "innovative" solutions to this? Making a native app is out of the question because of the reasons we are doing a PWA in the first place.

We're pretty much experiencing the same issue: Web Push API notifications arent reliable (neither on iOS, nor Android). It's an internal business App, for only a handful of users, so PWA makes much more sense than a native app.
